# how to split image into multiple pices and join them as requested by user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to load a large image **( size > 80 MB)** into web page. User doesn't really need to see the whole image at once and only need to see the requested portion.

The dimensions of the image are approx **10k x 10k**.

I looked around a little bit but couldn't found a reasonable solution to the problem.

I would like to split the image into some amount of pieces as needed (for ex 9 pieces, 3k x 3k each) and load them into the page as user request or moves into next section of the image (ex. if user crosses **3k x 3k** boundary, server will send side or bottom piece as needed).

I did found ways how to split image but couldn't find a way to do that dynamically and sew them together dynamically.

**UPDATE**

I tried using **Microsoft Deep Zoom Composer** but it didn't work. I think it does not support such large image size. I came to that conclusion as I tried the same image in **Microsoft PhotoSynth** and got an error message that it only supports files up to **32MB**. **Deep Zoom Composer** and **Photo Synth** use same file format so I think they might have same file size constraints.

Deep zoom Composer didn't produced meaningful error message as the error message was, **file format is not right**, but file is in right format (i.e. jpg).
Thanks

Comment: This may be a silly question but why do you need to create a new image if you have the original?  Is the user manipulating it in some way?

Comment: @EbenRoux I am not creating new image, I want image to be loaded into pieces and then put together as individual piece gets loaded into client browser. Really don't want to load whole **80 MegaBytes** or more at once if user doesn't need to see it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Microsoft Deep Zoom Composer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409068.aspx)

Comment: doesn't look like `Microsoft Deep Zoom Composer` supports such large image files as I couldn't import the image file into it. File opens properly in widows image preview and picassa.

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a rather large image to display I am going to assume you cannot size it to more manageable dimensions and you have to show it in some grid.  You could use the same idea as Google Maps where you load the blocks individually as the user moves across the view.

How you are going to structure that view will be up to you since even 3k x 3k pixels is somewhat larger than most screen resolutions.  You may want even smaller blocks.

I don't know of any component off-hand to do what you require but rolling your own shouldn't be too difficult.  You could use some container `div` with the grid `div`s arranged inside and as each comes into view you load the background image bit or you could render a fixed number of `div`s as your grid and load the necessary background images as your "viewport" moves.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, need to maintain the original resolution of the image as its for a specific application. I also thought of doing it like google maps but don't really know how to implement it. I'll be willing to use some off the shelf solution if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should convert it to another file format, for example bmp, so you can easyly navigate in the file to the needed pixels, compose a new image with those pixels and send it, or save it and reerence it. The big problem would be the new image size.

Comment: Deep Zoom Composer made it really easy for me, I was able to integrate and automate the whole system using MDZ library.